# std::getline breaks if stdin is replaced by pipe of another process

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, process, pipe

I have a simple example program that reads from std::cin and writes to std::cout. It works fine if run in cmd.exe or the visual studio debugger. The code (server.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        if (input == "dog")
        {
            std::cout << "cat" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (input == "white")
        {
            std::cout << "black" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (input == "quit")
        {
            std::cout << "exiting" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (input != "")
        {
            std::cout << "unknown" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want to run this from another process that writes to its stdin and reads from its stdout. I create two pipes and start a process using CreateProcess with the read handle of one pipe as StdInput handle and the write handle of the other pipe as Stdouput handle. The Code (client.cpp):

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

namespace
{
    class Server
    {
    public:
        Server() :
            m_pi()
        {
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)};
            sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
            assert(CreatePipe(&m_ro, &m_wo, &sa, 0));
            assert(SetHandleInformation(m_ro, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0));
            assert(CreatePipe(&m_ri, &m_wi, &sa, 0));
            assert(SetHandleInformation(m_ri, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0));

            STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFO)};
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
            si.hStdInput = m_ri;
            si.hStdOutput = m_wo;

            assert(CreateProcess(L"..\\Debug\\server.exe", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, &si, &m_pi));
        }

        ~Server()
        {
            execute("quit\n");
            assert(WaitForSingleObject(m_pi.hProcess, INFINITE) != WAIT_FAILED);

            assert(CloseHandle(m_pi.hThread));
            assert(CloseHandle(m_pi.hProcess));
            assert(CloseHandle(m_wi));
            assert(CloseHandle(m_ri));
            assert(CloseHandle(m_wo));
            assert(CloseHandle(m_ro));
        }

        std::string execute(std::string const& cmd)
        {
            DWORD num_bytes;
            assert(WriteFile(m_wi, cmd.c_str(), (DWORD)cmd.size(), &num_bytes, 0));

            std::string output;

            DWORD n = 0;
            while (n == 0)
            {
                Sleep(0);

                assert(PeekNamedPipe(m_ro, 0, 0, 0, &n, 0));
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    output.resize(n);
                    assert(ReadFile(m_ro, &output[0], n, &num_bytes, 0));
                }
            }

            return output;
        }

    private:
        HANDLE m_wo, m_ro, m_wi, m_ri;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION m_pi;
    };

    Server g_server;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << g_server.execute("white\n") << std::endl;
    std::cout << g_server.execute("foobar\n") << std::endl;
    std::cout << g_server.execute("dog\n") << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that the client only receives the massage "error", so the std::cin of the server seems to be broken.

My question is, what did I do wrong?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" - to start with, you coded `while (true) { getline... }` instead of `while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) { use input... }`.  Fix that and you'll at least notice when your input attempt hits EOF/disconnection.

Comment: @Tony D: thanks, I changed the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're disabling inheritance for the handle that the child will use to read from `stdin` - the child needs to inherit that handle.  Instead of:

```
SetHandleInformation(m_ri, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
```

Try the following to disable inheritance on the handle that the server process will use to write to the child's `stdin`:

```
SetHandleInformation(m_wi, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. But the code works also without any calls to SetHandleInformation. My source was this example: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I'm not sure why it is necessary at all to disable inheritance for one of the handles of a pipe.

Comment: I think the reasons for marking the handles non-inheritable is: 1) to protect them from accidental use by the child process, since the child has no business with those ends of the pipes (just general process=level protection of resources) and 2) if the child were a long-living process (maybe it lives longer than the parent), it wouldn't have a way to close the handles and therefore the pipes would 'leak'.